# Platform-specific graphic device

Tags: r

I'd like to write a function that takes a filename and produces a .pdf file on a *nix platform and a .wmf on a windows platform with that filename and width of 6 inches height 4.

```
graph <- function(filename){
setwd("graphics")
ext <- ifelse(.Platform$OS.type == "unix", "pdf", "wmf")
name <- paste(filename, ext, sep=".")
ifelse(.Platform$OS.type == "unix", pdf(name, width=6, height=4), wmf(name, width=6, height=4))
}
```

That's my attempt but I'm getting this error

Error in ans[test & !nas] <- rep(yes, length.out = length(ans))[test &  : 
  replacement has length zero

any ideas? I feel like I'm overlooking something.

Comment: oh also the first ifelse works, it's the second where the error occurred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that ifelse returns a value, *not* do whatever is in the arguments. I've learned this the hard way before: **ifelse != shorthand if**, ifelse = vectorized if. From the help page:

> ifelse(test, yes, no)
>
> 'ifelse' returns a value with the same
>   shape as 'test' which is
>        filled with elements selected from either 'yes' or 'no' depending
>        on whether the element of 'test' is 'TRUE' or 'FALSE'.

So just use something like:

```
if (.Platform$OS.type == "unix") {
  pdf(name, width=6, height=4) 
} else {
  wmf(name, width=6, height=4)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a somewhat more polished version of your function.  Improvements:

- doesn't mess with your working directory
- avoids the duplicated if statement by looking up the device function from the extension

->

```
graph <- function(filename) {
  ext <- if(.Platform$OS.type == "unix") "pdf" else "wmf"
  dev <- match.fun(ext)
  path <- paste("graphics/", filename, ".", ext, sep = "")

  dev(path, width = 6, height = 4)
}
```

Comment: I don't think this works. On my Windows installation, match.fun("pdf") works, but match.fun("wmf") fails. Where is the wmf() function? It's not in grDevices...